# javax.smarcardio unknown exception 0x1f

Tags: java, session, smartcard, apdu, smartcard-reader

I'm working on a card reader now. I want to take data from the card. I took uid. I want to take encrypted data. So I want to enter the secure mode and start session. I did something. I send a command apdu to start session but every time return unknown exception 0x1f here is the code.

```
    TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();

    List<CardTerminal> terminals = factory.terminals().list();

    terminal = terminals.get(0);
    card = terminal.connect("T=1");
    CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();
    byte[] c1 = { (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x72, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x18, (byte) 0x5c, (byte) 0xc5,
            (byte) 0x0a, (byte) 0xa2, (byte) 0x5b, (byte) 0x38, (byte) 0x7f, (byte) 0x81, (byte) 0x3a, (byte) 0x3d,
            (byte) 0x1a, (byte) 0x88, (byte) 0x7d, (byte) 0x26, (byte) 0xfc, (byte) 0x2b, (byte) 0xa8, (byte) 0xa7,
            (byte) 0xdd, (byte) 0xdc, (byte) 0x71, (byte) 0xe0, (byte) 0xf3, (byte) 0xc6 };

    ResponseAPDU response = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(0xFF, 0x00,0x00,0x00,c1,5,24));
```

This code returns me 6a81( it means function not supported),

if I send directly start session command(84 72 00 00) this time returns unknown exception.

Please help me. You don't have to find the error in code. Tell me How Can I Start Session in a Smart Card. I use HID OMNİKEY 5021 CL.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.smartcardio.CardException: sun.security.smartcardio.PCSCException: Unknown error 0x1f
at sun.security.smartcardio.ChannelImpl.doTransmit(ChannelImpl.java:219)
at sun.security.smartcardio.ChannelImpl.transmit(ChannelImpl.java:90)
at CardReader.GetUID.getUID(GetUID.java:48)
at CardReader.GetUID.main(GetUID.java:86)
```

Comment: What type of card do you want to access? Wht protocol does the card speak?

Comment: Terminals: [PC/SC terminal OMNIKEY CardMan 5x21-CL 0]
card: PC/SC card in OMNIKEY CardMan 5x21-CL 0, protocol T=1

Comment: I meant the contactless smartcard / tag, not the terminal...

Comment: T=CL, MIFARE®, iCLASS® / ISO 14443 A with 848 Kbps transmission rate
(depending on card),
ISO 14443 B with 848 Kbps transmission rate (depending on card),
ISO 15693 with 26 Kbps transmission rate (depending on card)   and you can look this pdf https://www.hidglobal.com/sites/default/files/resource_files/omnikey-5021-cl-usb-reader-ds-en.pdf

Comment: I'm aware of what protocols/card the reader supports. The problem is that you need need to speak differently with the reader depending on the actuial type of card. Thus it's impossible to anwer your question without knowing what card **you** use with the reader.

Comment: I'm using normal smartcard. İn my .net project apdu command 84 72 00 00 18 ,(24 byte) data but in java I take exception. What is diferences between java and .net. If it is different protocol, apdu commands didn' work in .net. It is working in .net but it doesn't work in java.  http://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.com.tr/2010/06/pcsc-sample-in-java.html ı tried this code. It doesnt work. Same exception.

Comment: Did you try `ResponseAPDU response = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(0x84, 0x72,0x00,0x00,c1,5,24));`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem is byte types .net and java. C# byte type between 0 and 255 but java byte type -127 and +128. So if I send a higher than 127 value to java, card interpret like minus value.

Answer (score 1):

APDU you're sending is wrong, because you use `CommandAPDU` in an incorrect way.

`new CommandAPDU(0xFF, 0x00,0x00,0x00,c1,5,24)`

creates an APDU starting `FF000000185CC50AA2...` which is not what you (probably) want.

Try `new CommandAPDU(0x84, 0x72,0x00,0x00,c1,5,24)` instead.

See [CommandAPDU javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/CommandAPDU.html) and [APDU format description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_card_application_protocol_data_unit).